# What is the significance of "with" in this context:

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

**To get over----** to overcome an unpleasant situation.

An example in *Cambridge dictionary:*

> I'll be glad to get these exams over **with.**

What if I would omit the **'with'**?
Would it change the meaning?

Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

The "with" addition acts as an intensifier, which is a way of adding strong emphasis to the statement. Here are three ways of saying you want to be finished with something, in ascending order of intensity:

> I just want to get this over.
>   I just want to get this over with.
>   I just want to get this over and done with.

These all mean the same thing. The intensity of feeling is the only difference.